Did Gauss criticize cardinals?
In a well-known passage, Gauss criticized the use of infinity in mathematics in the following terms:

I protest first of all against the use of an infinite quantity as a completed one, which is never permissible in mathematics. The infinite is only a façon de parler, where one is really speaking of limits to which certain ratios come as close as one likes while others are allowed to grow without restriction.

This has often been interpreted by historians as rejection of "completed" infinity, also known as actual infinity (and contrasted with potential infinity).  Actual infinity is considered to have been "tamed" by Cantor, who based his theory of infinite ordinals and cardinals on the idea of actual infinity.  Hilbert famously referred to such a framework as a "Cantorian paradise".
However, other historians give a different interpretation of Gauss' passage. Waterhouse points out in

WILLIAM C. WATERHOUSE, GAUSS ON INFINITY, Historia Mathematica 6 (1979), 430-436

that the context of Gauss's passage is a criticism of a contemporary mathematician's attempted proof of the parallel postulate, using the idea of a circle of a radius of infinite magnitude.  Accordingly, it is not infinite cardinals but rather infinite magnitudes that are rejected by Gauss.  Such infinite magnitudes were formalized in nonstandard analysis, and can be called infinite ringinals (because they are elements of a ring such as the ring of integers), to contrast them with Cantorian infinities.
This leads us to the following question: Did Gauss criticize infinite cardinals or infinite ringinals?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
